# Changing the application icon dynamically with activity alias

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two icons in the API, and I want the application icon to be the 1st icon from the API when Button 1 is pressed, and the 2nd icon from the API when Button 2 is pressed. How can I achieve this?

I couldn't achieve it using the API, but I managed to save the local icons and use them with aliases.

```
<activity-alias
            android:name="OneLauncherAlias"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_verisoft1"
            android:label="@string/verisoft_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the App Icon and Name dynamically by following method.

```
 <activity-alias
            android:name=".SplashActivityAlias1"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_1"
            android:label="Calculator"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_1"
            android:targetActivity=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".SplashActivityAlias2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_2"
            android:label="Calculator"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_2"
            android:targetActivity=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

You have to add Multiple Alias for Laucher activity as many Icons you want to change. Like this.

```
val pm = packageManager
                            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                                ComponentName(
                                    this,
                                    "com.photovideolocker.SplashActivity"
                                ),
                                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                            )
                            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                                ComponentName(
                                    this,
                                    "com.photovideolocker.SplashActivityAlias1"
                                ),
                                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                            )
                            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                                ComponentName(
                                    this,
                                    "com.photovideolocker.SplashActivityAlias2"
                                ),
                                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                            )
```

You can enable and disable the icon you want to set by this method.

Comment: Why does PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP cause the close app? Is there any way to do this without closing?

Comment: @MuratÖter because you disable the activity, no other way

Comment: @user924 Yes, I experienced. There is no way to icon changes without app close. All of them workaround